# Code Coverage with chutzpah resulting in timeout error

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, nunit, typescript, chutzpah

I am using Chutzpah Version 3.2.3 with Typescript and nUnit.

I am able to successfully run the unit tests. But when i do cod coverage for the same unit tests i get

```
Error: Timeout occurred when executing test file
```

I have no clue where to even start looking to fix it. I have been banging my head about this issue for a day now, Any leads are highly appreciated.

Below is my chutzpah.json

```
{
"Framework": "qunit",
"TestHarnessLocationMode": "Custom",
"TestHarnessDirectory": "../example.exampleTest.Client.Excel.Web/App",

"Compile": {
    "Mode": "External",
    "Extensions": [ ".ts" ],
    "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ],
    "SourceDirectory": "../../Example.exampleTest/",
    "OutDirectory": "../../Example.exampleTest/"
}
```

}

Comment: Couple things
1. Run with the openinbrowser flag or debug flag and open the built html file in the browser. You can often see more errors about what it is trying to do there

2. Please file a repro on chutzpah.codeplex.com and I can take a look at it.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by being specific about which files to include in code coverage and which files to exclude. Below is my updated chutzpah.json

```
{
"Framework": "qunit",
"EnableCodeCoverage ": "true",
"CodeCoverageIncludes": [
    "*Orchestrator*",
    "*Transformer*",
    "*Processor*"
],
"CodeCoverageExcludes": [
    "*\\Example.Example.Client.Excel.Web\\App\\Workstreams\\AX-AX\\*",
    "*\\Example.Example.Client.Excel.Web\\App\\Workstreams\\CS\\v1.0\\CS-ICS\\*",
    "*\\Example.Example.Client.Excel.Web\\App\\Workstreams\\CAD-CAD\\*",
    "*\\Example.Example.Client.Excel.Web\\App\\AddInModules\\*",
    "*\\Example.Example.Client.Excel.Web\\Scripts\\*",
    "*\\Example.Example.Client.Excel.Web\\Mocks\\*"
],

"TestFileTimeout":"200000", 
"Compile": {
    "Mode": "External",
    "Extensions": [ ".ts" ],
    "ExtensionsWithNoOutput": [ ".d.ts" ],
    "SourceDirectory": "../../Example.Example/",
    "OutDirectory": "../../Example.Example/"
}
}
```